# In the SonarQube Marketplace, what does it mean for a plugin to be incompatible?

Tags: sonarqube

I just upgraded from SonarQube 6.1 to 6.7.7. For SonarJava, it automatically installed 4.15.0.12310 (it was 4.10.0.10260 before). In the Marketplace, when I hover over the available versions from 5.0-5.13, it says “Incompatible”. When I hover over 5.13.1+, it says “Requires system update”. What does it mean for it to be incompatible if it doesn’t require a system update?

I am seeing this with various other plugins as well, such as SonarPython, which had 1.8 automatically installed. I had to manually install 1.9.1 in order to get this bug fix (which is why I originally upgraded the server): https://community.sonarsource.com/t/python-s1481-code-smell-unused-local-variables-should-be-removed-false-positive-with-string-interpolation/8961

I could manually install newer versions of other plugins as well, but I don’t know if that’s safe.

I also can’t find an official plugin compatibility matrix, since this only shows 7.9+: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

`Incompatible` means that the plugin does not work with the version of SonarQube you have installed.

An example of an incompatible plugin would be one where the plugin relied on an API that was removed in your current SonarQube version. You may be able to use that version of the plugin if you downgraded your SonarQube instance to a previous version.

`Requires system update` means you need to upgrade SonarQube in order to install the plugin.

For what it's worth, the states as described by the API documentation are:

```
Update status values are:
COMPATIBLE: plugin is compatible with current SonarQube instance.
INCOMPATIBLE: plugin is not compatible with current SonarQube instance.
REQUIRES_SYSTEM_UPGRADE: plugin requires SonarQube to be upgraded before being installed.
DEPS_REQUIRE_SYSTEM_UPGRADE: at least one plugin on which the plugin is dependent requires SonarQube to be upgraded.
```